# Filter rows with a certain suffix

Tags: r, regex, filter, subset, grepl

I have 12 columns of data in a table called df, the first column contains several thousand strings such as `AA150502-01, AA150502-02, BB150502-01, BB150502-03, etc`.

I want to filter the table so that I only see the rows ending with the suffix `"-01"`, how do I do this?

I so far have:

```
myd <- subset(df, Date_ID == 'AA150502-01')
```

I need to use some kind of wildcard characters for the prefix which precedes `"-01"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a regular expression.  For example:

```
myd <- subset(df, grepl("-01$", Date_ID))
```

or

```
myd <- df[grep("-01$", df$Date_ID),]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the `dplyr` solution just in case you want to use it:

```
data %>% filter(grepl("-01$", Date_ID))
```